# How to make travis ci build failing graphic different for each git branch

Tags: github, travis-ci

So I have this github repo with multiple branches here: https://github.com/WalnutiQ/WalnutiQ
and a build passing badge from travis ci on the main README.md

Whenever I push a commit to any branch if it fails the travis ci graphic will show build failing for all branches. Is there a easy way to make it so that it will show build failing just for that one branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this counts as an easy way, but here's what I do.

**Build Script:**

- Have my build script stamp the build failing at start, by copying a badge to the product dir.
- Upon completion stamp the build passing.

Something [like this](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/blob/master/build.sh).

**Publish Script**

The publish script runs after the main build, whether it passed or failed.

- Run a [script to copy and push](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/blob/master/publish-build-results.sh) the resulting passed or fail badge on the gh-pages branch, in a folder called [build-status](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/tree/gh-pages/build-status).
- As you can see this folder should have an [.htaccess](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/blob/gh-pages/build-status/.htaccess) file to allow the image to be refreshed quickly. Don't put this file in the root folder of your project, otherwise GitHub will probably stop supporting it.

Then serve it up on the branch's README.md with:

`![Build Status](http://www.typhoonframework.org/build-status/build-status.png)`

. . . the above, pasted verbatim into StackOverflow, which also accepts markdown format, looks like:

[Build Status http://www.typhoonframework.org/build-status/build-status.png?q=z](http://www.typhoonframework.org/build-status/build-status.png?q=z)

If you want to do this per-branch, just modify the script to include the branch name in the badge, and have the branch's README point to that.

**Why I like this approach:**

In general and where possible like to create scripts that are build-server agnostic.

- I can change build server if I ever need to.
- The above build script, which is 68 lines compiles and tests on two platforms and then produces a [code coverage report](http://appsquick.broke-it.net/artifact/TPN-TC/JOB1/build-448/reports/iOS_Simulator/coverage/index.html) and [API documentation](http://typhoonframework.org/docs/latest/api/group___factory.html) before publishing the results. Its written in a language which dev's already understand, so they don't have to invest in learning the specific YAML (yet another) format that the build server provides.
- It allows developers to easily run the build-script on their local workstation, from a clean checkout. This way they can run the script *before* they commit, and the likelihood of a build-fail and subsequent impact to other devs is less.
- If there is a build failure its easy to reproduce and diagnose the problem locally.

Having said that a status badge is a good example of a value add that can be provided by a build server if convenient to use.